# Comparing two array and matching elements based on boolean

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Let's say I have two arrays

```
let array1 = [1,2,3]
let array2 = [false, true, false]
```

I'd like to return the list of values from array1 that matches `true` boolean at certain index. In this simple example this would be `[2]`

How to achieve it using functional approach?

Comment: Is a custom struct with an `Int` and a `Bool` member an option since we are dealing with an object oriented language?

Comment: yup, but all I look for is some nifty combination of `map` and `zip` I guess :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Zip" the arrays, then map each pair to the first element or 
`nil`, depending on the second element. `flatMap()` returns only 
the non-nil results:

```
let array1 = [1,2,3]
let array2 = [false, true, false]

let result = zip(array1, array2).flatMap { $1 ? $0 : nil }
print(result) // [2]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you, you are always helpful!

Comment: Very nice and simple!